# SVN Pre-Commit for build systems

Tags: linux, svn

What is the best script for a SVN Pre commit to only allows commits that contain the following string

issue 1234

This is to help our build system tag the ticket in our bug system while talking to the svn repo

Something like

---

if comment includes

issue 1234

then commit

otherwise

fail "please enter issue "

---

This is for a SVN linux configuration

Comment: There are plenty of example SVN hooks. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2):

There is a great pre-commit log entry query example shown at http://blog.grimsy.net/2008/07/a-few-svn-pre-commit-hooks/